# Creating sequenced tabs in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qtabwidget

A program has the main window, the menu bar, the menu item (**QAction** in **Qt**), the tab widget, the text edit. I try to receive the sequenced numeration in the tabs when I press on the menu item (New Tab).

When I press on the **New Tab** then **tab 1**, **tab 2**, **tab 3**, **tab 4** and so on must appear.

The suggested approximate code is here:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent):QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QMenuBar* menuBar = new QMenuBar(this);
    setMenuBar(menuBar);

    QMenu* fileMenu = new QMenu("&File", this);
    menuBar->addMenu(fileMenu);

    QAction* newTabAction = new QAction("&New Tab", this);
    fileMenu->addAction(newTabAction);
    connect(newTabAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newTabActionHandler()));

    QTabWidget* tabWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
    QList<QWidget*> widgetList;
    widgetList.append(new QWidget(this));
    tabWidget->addTab(widgetList[0], "Tab 0");
    tabWidget->setMovable(true);
    tabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);
    QList<QTextEdit*> textEditList;
    textEditList.append(new QTextEdit(this));
    QVBoxLayout* vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    widgetList[0]->setLayout(vBoxLayout);
    vBoxLayout->addWidget(textEditList[0]);
    setCentralWidget(tabWidget);
}

void MainWindow::newTabActionHandler()
{
    widgetList.append(new QWidget(this));
    tabWidget->addTab(widgetList[widgetList.size()-1], ????);
    textEditList.append(new QTextEdit(this));
    QVBoxLayout* vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    widgetList[widgetList.size()-1]->setLayout(vBoxLayout);
    vBoxLayout->addWidget(textEditList[textEditList.size()-1]);
}
```

Please, put the correct code into the line where question signs take place to be (in the **newTabActionHandler()** method body).

```
tabWidget->addTab(widgetList[widgetList.size()-1], ????);
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to order your code, in this case you only need to use the size of the list. but I have given the freedom to correct your code, for example widgetList and textEditList are local variables so you can not access from the slot so it is appropriate that they are members of the class.

Another recommendation is to order your code, the more readable your code is, so you can create widget and textedit and make your links without using your containers.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void newTabActionHandler();

private:
    QList<QWidget*> widgetList;
    QList<QTextEdit*> textEditList;
    QTabWidget* tabWidget;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QMenu>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{

    QMenuBar *menuBar = new QMenuBar(this);
    setMenuBar(menuBar);

    QMenu* fileMenu = new QMenu("&File", this);
    menuBar->addMenu(fileMenu);

    QAction *newTabAction = new QAction("&New Tab", this);
    fileMenu->addAction(newTabAction);
    connect(newTabAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::newTabActionHandler);

    tabWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
    tabWidget->setMovable(true);
    tabWidget->setTabsClosable(true);
    newTabActionHandler();

    setCentralWidget(tabWidget);
}

void MainWindow::newTabActionHandler()
{
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    widgetList << widget;
    tabWidget->addTab(widget, QString("Tab %1").arg(widgetList.size()-1));

    QTextEdit *textEdit =  new QTextEdit;
    textEditList << textEdit;
    QVBoxLayout* vBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    vBoxLayout->addWidget(textEdit);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

You can find the complete example in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49096407)

Comment: I entered the right code chunk and the program started to work as I need. Thank you. This theme may be completed.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ???? by `QString("Tab %1").arg(widgetList.size()-1)`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19001639)

Comment: Why doesn't this answer the question @André? I admit I don't know much C++, but matt's answer seems to answer it exactly as the OP requested.

Comment: You are right @Ben. I didnt read the question good enough during the review. But this answer could use a bit explaning to make it even better and explain why this line of code answers the question.